# What is m3.medium + RHEL 6.5 equivalent in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using  m3.medium AWS instance for my application with following configuration.

- OS: Red Hat Linux Enterprise Edition 6.5 (RHEL 6.5)
- CPU: 1
- Processor: Intel Xeon E5-2670
- RAM: 4GB

What is m3.medium + RHEL 6.5 equivalent in Microsoft Azure?

Comment: Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the A Series VMs the closest you'd get would be an A2. You could try one of the new D Series VMs but they cost a fair bit more (STANDARD_D1) would be closest.

RHEL isn't supported on Azure (officially) so the closest fully supported drop you'd get would be CentOS (see here for your options: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-endorsed-distributions/)